# is it possible to use Jmeter for testing OPC ua?

Tags: jmeter, opc

I have a tests for mqtt in jmeter. i want to use jmeter for sending opc ua requests using jmeter.
is it possible to use Jmeter for testing OPC ua?
can we send opc client requests via jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box JMeter doesn't support OPC UA protocol, also there are no [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) offering such functionality (at least I'm not aware of any) so  you will either have to find a client library like [Java Based OPC UA Client SDK](https://www.unified-automation.com/products/client-sdk/java-ua-client-sdk.html) or [OPC UA Java Stack](http://opcfoundation.github.io/UA-Java-Legacy/) and program the requests you need to send using [JSR223 Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/) language (valid Java code in the majority of cases will be valid Groovy code, or if you prefer "pure" Java you can consider [developing your own JMeter Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-develop-a-jmeter-plugin-intro-and-best-practices)) or do some reverse engineering of OPC UA protocol if above SDKs are not fulfilling your requirements.